# How to get a specific value from sql into a php file which (the value) is passed through angular js

Tags: php, sql, angularjs

```
$data = [
'merchantId'        => 'M100003360', // To be replace by integration merchant ID
'qrCode'            => '968566222112615382',
'curType'           => 'RM',
'notifyURL'         => 'https://google.com/',
'merOrderNo'        => uniqid(),
'goodsName'         => ,
'orderAmt'          => 'This is where I want to pull the value from sql',
'remark'            => '',
'transactionType'   => '1',
];

$data = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

But I would only want to get a specific value so is there a way to filter out?? Without using WHERE clause as I want it to be dynamic.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I think this is a subjective question - there's no fixed answer. Instead, why don't you post what you've tried?